# In flutter, how can I call biometric login method at initial state?

Tags: flutter, biometrics

In my flutter project, I want to call the biometric login at the `init()` state of the login screen (Stateful class). But this can't be done and get error. How can I fix this? Or please guide me some way to implement this.

What I expecting is when user enter the application after splash screen, if there is enable for biometric login in app in previous time. Biometric popup dialog will appear and user can login with that biometric or user can login manually with password.

This is my code.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    authenticateWithBiometric(isEnabled: true);
    super.initState();
  }

Future<void> authenticateWithBiometric(
      {required bool isEnabled}) async {
    bool didAuthenticate = false;
    print('AvailableBiometric === $availableBiometric');
    if (isEnabled) {
      if (availableBiometric.isEmpty) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => const AlertDialog(
            title: Text(FINGER_PRINT_NOT_REGISTER),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        try {
          setState(() {
            _authorizedStatus = BiometricAuthState.authenticating;
          });

          didAuthenticate = await bioAuth.authenticate(
            localizedReason: "Touch sensor to authenticate",
            authMessages: [],
            options: const AuthenticationOptions(
                stickyAuth: false, biometricOnly: true),
          );
          setState(() {
            _authorizedStatus = BiometricAuthState.authenticating;
          });
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          developer.log('auth error', error: e);
          setState(() {
            _authorizedStatus = BiometricAuthState.authenticating;
          });
        }
      }
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        _authorizedStatus = didAuthenticate
            ? BiometricAuthState.authorized
            : BiometricAuthState.notAuthorized;
        _biometricAuthTypeForApi =
        _authorizedStatus == BiometricAuthState.authorized
            ? 'fingerprint'
            : 'none';
      });
      if (_authorizedStatus == BiometricAuthState.authorized) {
        // confirmPasswordModalBottomSheet(
        //     biometricAuthRegBloc: biometricAuthRegBloc, isEnabled: isEnabled);
      }
    } else {
      // confirmPasswordModalBottomSheet(
      //     biometricAuthRegBloc: biometricAuthRegBloc, isEnabled: isEnabled);
    }
  }
```

And I got this error

> E/flutter (11521): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
> Unhandled Exception:
> dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_LocalizationsScope>() or
> dependOnInheritedElement() was called before
> _LoginBodyState.initState() completed. E/flutter (11521): When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of()
> changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's
> reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an
> initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect
> the changes in the inherited widget. E/flutter (11521): Typically
> references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build()
> methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can
> be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after
> initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.